# How to swap fragment on home page (and fix java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f08007c)

Tags: java, android

Currently I'm using the default Navigation Drawer Activity structure in Android Studio. I have a button at a fragment_home.xml. I wanted the button to have a onClickListener, and when user taps on it, the user redirects to another fragment xml file, in this case, from Home Fragment to Collection Fragment.

By default, there will be a hamburger menu for users to select the fragment. But in this case, I want the users to be able to select the fragment directly on the home fragment as well.

I have this code in HomeFragment (the first fragment page user will see):

```
private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    //button to swap the fragment to collection fragment

    Button button = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.runCollection);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment = new CollectionFragment();

            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.mobile_navigation, fragment)
                    .commit();

        }
    });

    return root;
}}
    });
```

`R.id.mobile_navigation` is referring to the mobile_navigation.xml under res>navigation, as seen below:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_home"
    android:name="com.xxx.ui.home.HomeFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_collection"
    android:name="com.xxx.ui.collection.CollectionFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_collection"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_collection" />

</navigation>
```

Currently, when I press the button, the app crashes, and the log will show the following error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f08007c (com.xxxx.appname:id/mobile_navigation) for fragment CollectionFragment{47e0622 #1 id=0x7f08007c}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                 Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.nav_home_to_nav_collection);
            }
        });
```

**Add destinations to the navigation graph**

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_home"
    android:name="com.xxx.ui.home.HomeFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">

     <action
        android:id="@+id/nav_home_to_nav_collection"
        app:destination="@id/nav_collection" />

 </fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_collection"
    android:name="com.xxx.ui.collection.CollectionFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_collection"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_collection" />

</navigation>
```

[Get started with the Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#java)